# RegEx formula for copying comma-separated target glossary terms to a new line

Tags: regex

I have a tab-separated two columns glossary that contains mostly target, rarely source terms separated by a comma and followed by white-space like:

- abarbeiten-TAB-execute, perform

and

- denken, überlegen-TAB-think, reflect

I need a regex formula for achieving the following result

- abarbeiten-TAB-execute
- abarbeiten-TAB-perform
- denken-TAB-think
- denken-TAB-reflect
- überlegen-TAB-think
- überlegen-TAB-reflect

Could anyone please provide me with one?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That does not look like a problem to solve with a `regex`...

Comment: Thanks for quick respond! So, how or with what could I achive the above result?

Comment: @Gezegen Use a basic scripting language. For example, paste the following into your address bar: `javascript:y=[],s=prompt().split("-").map(function(v){return v.split(/, */)});for(i in s[0])for(j in s[2])y.push(s[0][i]+'-'+s[1]+'-'+s[2][j]);document.write("<pre>"+y.join("\n"))`.